# Blazor component not refreshing after adding entry to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on simple app to manage hotel reservations in Blazor server side, using EF Core for database. I have a Adding form for Rooms in hotel, and at the same page I'm showing list of all rooms, and Im currently facing an issue with that when i'm adding a new room the component is not refreshing itself I have to click F5 to so my list gets populated again. I've found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40njRXr6eUo) on youtube he is doing something similar and it works for him. I've also tried to put StateHasChanged in my page code, and nothing happend.

Heres page code:

```
@page "/rooms"
@using HotelServiceSystem.Interfaces.Services
@using HotelServiceSystem.Entities
@inject IRoomService roomService

<h3>Rooms</h3>
<div class="col-12">
    <hr/>
    <EditForm Model="@ModelRoom" OnSubmit="@SaveRoom">
        <div class="col-12 row">
            <label class="col-2">Room number</label>
            <InputText class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="ModelRoom.RoomIdentifier"/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="col-12 row">
            <label class="col-2">Floor</label>
            <InputNumber class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="ModelRoom.Floor"/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="col-12 row">
            <label class="col-2">Number of beds</label>
            <InputNumber class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="ModelRoom.NumberOfBeds"/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="col-12 row">
            <span class="col-2"></span>
            <input type="submit" class="form-control col-1 btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="submit" class="form-control col-1 btn btn-primary" value="Clear"/>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
    
    <div class="col-10">
        <h3>Rooms</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Room number</th>
                <th>Capacity</th>
                <th>Number of beds</th>
                <th>Floor</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Is free?</th>
                <th>Is out of service?</th>
                <th>Need cleaning?</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @if (RoomList != null)
            {
                foreach (var room in RoomList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@room.RoomIdentifier</td>
                        <td>@room.GuestsCapacity</td>
                        <td>@room.NumberOfBeds</td>
                        <td>@room.Floor</td>
                        <td>@room.Price</td>
                        <td>@room.IsFree</td>
                        <td>@room.IsOutOfService</td>
                        <td>@room.ShouldBeCleaned</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <h3>..Loading</h3>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private List<Room> RoomList { get; set; }
    private Room ModelRoom { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ModelRoom = new Room();
        RoomList = roomService.GetAllRoomsAsync();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private async void SaveRoom()
    {
        ModelRoom.RoomReservations = new List<RoomReservation>();
        ModelRoom.IsFree = true;
        ModelRoom.IsOutOfService = false;
        ModelRoom.ShouldBeCleaned = false;
        await roomService.AddRoomAsync(ModelRoom);
        ModelRoom = new Room();
    }
}
```

Thanks for help I've been looking for solution for about few hours

Comment: You forgot to update `RoomList`, like this: `await roomService.AddRoomAsync(ModelRoom); RoomList.Add(ModelRoom);StateHasChanged();`

Comment: Yeah I can see but the guy on video does not do it either, it's probably coming from database, or not?

Comment: It works now but I have a strange issue if my method for saving data is in this case SaveRoom and it's asynchronus metod I have to click on submit 2 times to save it, does any one  know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `OnValidSubmit = "@SaveRoom"` instead of  `OnSubmit="@SaveRoom"`

and the return type of the `SaveRoom` method should be `Task`, not `void`, like the following.

```
private async Task SaveRoom()
 {
       
 }
```

Why do you use 2 "submit" buttons ? Remove the second...